# How to import modules dynamically in angular

Tags: angular

using `import('some.component')` will tell angular compiler to compile the imported component and create a chunk in the dist folder

how can I tell angular compile to create lazy loadable chunks for all the files inside a folder without importing them one by one ?

the goal is to be able to import the modules dynamically using `import(componentName)` but without the mess of writing import statements for all available modules in one file

the project is part of an nx workspace

Edit: so far I managed to figure out that angular does not like variables when it comes to import

```
  data!: any

  constructor(
    protected firestore: Firestore,
  ) {
    if (this.data) {
      //this will force angular to create a lazy loadable chunk
      import('db/item.write')
    }
  }

  save(data: any, options: any) {

    //this fails but I can see the chunk is being created 
    const writer = 'db/item.write'
    from(import(writer)).subscribe((x: any) => console.log(x.default))

    //this works 
    from(import('db/item.write')).subscribe((x:any)=>console.log(x.default))
    
  }
```

Comment: You can easily import module dynamically by binding module with router. I dont know if it's good for your use case ? You probably can do some redirection in your methods. An other solution it's to lazy load service that contain your business logic